# Cannot open App_Data Folder

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I am using MVC4 (the same applied while using MVC3). I somehow cannot open the `App_Data` folder. The data is there (the application can read it). But there is no way to collapse the folder to view the tables.

Can anyone give me a hint? I am trying out the tutorials, and one of them requires me to delete a certain table in the folder.

Comment: What happens if you go to the folder manually in windows? Can you access it then?

Comment: Thanks. I have the folder. How does one open the MDF file for viewing. Is a special software required to view it?

Answer (score 0):

To access the database itself you will need to use the server explorer.

Have a look at the following link, it should give you some pointers:

[Connect to Database](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms239722.aspx)

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks a lot. I can now view the data. Please excuse my tardy reply.

Comment: @KhathumetsoTsolo dont forget to select the tick next to my answer if it helped ;)